# Tkinter canvas not showing up

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I'm quite new to Tkinter and this is my first program, can anyone tell me why the canvas is not showing up? I'm not getting any errors so I assume it is working but just not visible? I tried moving it up a layer but it was still invisible. Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.master = master
        self.window()
        self.drawFigure()
        # self.master.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
        self.master.bind("<Escape>", self.end_fullscreen)

    def window(self):
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        screen_width = self.frame.winfo_screenwidth() / 2
        screen_height = self.frame.winfo_screenheight() / 2
        self.master.geometry('%dx%d' % (screen_width, screen_height))

    def end_fullscreen(self, event=None):
        self.master.attributes("-fullscreen", False)

    def drawFigure(self):
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.C = Canvas(self.frame, width=200, height=200, bg = 'red')
        self.C.pack()
        self.C.create_rectangle(50, 20, 150, 80, fill="#476042")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    w = Application(root)
    w.master.mainloop()
```

Appreciate all the input.

Comment: You need to decide which to use and call one of the `grid()`, `place()`, or `pack()` tkinter _layout manager_ methods to arrange your widgets. You're not doing it on all of them.

Comment: What are you trying to do with all these `Frame(self.master)` calls? I can tell you why that’s useless, but I can’t tell you what to do instead unless I know what you want them for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You import Tkinter **and** Tkinter as tk, which gets confusing.

`Application` inherits from Frame so you don't have to create additional frames inside. Certainly not more than one named `self.frame`.

How about this:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.window()
        self.drawFigure()
        self.master.bind("<Escape>", self.end_fullscreen)

    def window(self):
        screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth() / 2
        screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight() / 2
        self.master.geometry('%dx%d' % (screen_width, screen_height))

    def end_fullscreen(self, event=None):
        self.master.attributes("-fullscreen", False)

    def drawFigure(self):
        self.C = Canvas(self, width=200, height=200, bg = 'red')
        self.C.pack()
        self.C.create_rectangle(50, 20, 150, 80, fill="#476042")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    w = Application(root)
    w.master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Nice answer. **1** You could add `master.attributes('-fullscreen', True)` to the `__init__` method, so that `end_fullscreen` becomes useful. **2** You can change the screen width & height calculations to use `//` instead of `/`, so that in Python 3 the width & height are integers instead of floats. Those floats won't hurt anything here, since they get truncated by `'%dx%d'`, but it's still neater to calculate integers when you want integers.

Comment: BTW, it's much better to do `import Tkinter as tk`. That evil "star" import dumps 175 Tkinter names into your global namespace (136 names in Python 3), which is messy, and can potentially cause name collisions. But more importantly, the `tk` import makes it obvious which names are from Tkinter, so it makes the code easier to read.

Comment: Thank you very much! I see now that I didn't need to create so many frame instances, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call `pack()` on the Frame you created in `drawFigure()`:

```
def drawFigure(self):
    self.frame = Frame(self.master)
    self.frame.pack()                      # <--- There
    self.C = Canvas(self.frame, width=200, height=200, bg = 'red')
    self.C.pack()
    self.C.create_rectangle(50, 20, 150, 80, fill="#476042")
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re creating three sub frames of your parent, storing each of them as `self.frame` (so all but the last one are lost), and not placing any of them anywhere.

So, you’ve correctly placed the canvas on one of these invisible frames, but that doesn’t do any good.

I’m not sure what you’re trying to do with all these separate frames.

- If you really need three sibling frames, you have to store them in separate variables, or in a list, or something, and you need to place them.
- If you need one sibling frame, just create it once instead of three times, and again, you need to place it.
- If you need three or one child frames instead of sibling frames, create them with `self` rather than `self.master`.
- If you don’t need any sibling or child frames at all, don’t create them, and just place the canvas on `self` instead of `self.frame`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This really helps me in terms of general understanding. I didn't quite know how the Frame call works.